# Windows.Networking.EndpointPair constructor parameters

Tags: javascript, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I want to create a new EndpointPair object:

```js
// hostname is a string
// port is an integer

var endpointPair = new Windows.Networking.EndpointPair(null, null, hostname, port);
```

But I always get this error:

> 0x800a000d - JavaScript runtime error: Type mismatch

I've already tried the following:

- converting port to a string
- passing "" instead of null for the first two Parameters. (null should be okay if the documentation here, under the section Remarks, is right)
- passing no Parameters, but that ends up in an "too few parameters" error message

Above all, the documentation about the constructor has been removed (as of September 4, 2012): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.networking.endpointpair.endpointpair.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the documentation is completely wrong. The constructor is actually:

```
EndpointPair(Windows.Networking.HostName, string, Windows.Networking.HostName, string);
```

So you can use it as such:

```
var remoteHost = new Windows.Networking.HostName("foo");
var ep = new Windows.Networking.EndpointPair(null, null, remoteHost, "80");
```

You can see this when you look at the metadata for the remoteHost property is typed as `Windows.Networking.HostName`

Comment: I have already tried that, but then I get the following error: `0x800a13ee - JavaScript runtime error: EndpointPair: function called with too few arguments`.